# WINWORD Error when run in Task Scheduler "ExportAsFixedFormat"

Tags: powershell, ms-word, taskscheduler

I have a PowerShell script that leverages MS Word to convert txt files to .pdf.  When executing the script in the PowerShell window there is no problem - the script works fine and does what it is suppose to do.  However when executing this script from within the Task Scheduler MS Word fails when exporting the document as .pdf.  To be clear, the script is executing as a Scheduled Task, I know this because I am sending all the script output to a transcript file. In the transcript file I see the following error right at this line:

```
$doc.ExportAsFixedFormat( $outputFullPath , $wdExportFormatPDF )
```

This is the error.

```
PS>TerminatingError(Convert-Txt2Pdf): "Exception calling "ExportAsFixedFormat" with "2" argument(s): "Word has encountered a problem.""
Error Caught
Convert-Txt2Pdf : Exception calling "ExportAsFixedFormat" with "2" argument(s): "Word has encountered a problem."
At C:\Source\PowerShell\RunScripts\Run-Txt2Pdf2SP.ps1:55 char:9
+         Convert-Txt2Pdf `
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Convert-Txt2Pdf], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException,Convert-Txt2Pdf

Inner Exception
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.ExportAsFixedFormat(String OutputFileName, WdExportFormat ExportForma
t, Boolean OpenAfterExport, WdExportOptimizeFor OptimizeFor, WdExportRange Range, Int32 From, Int32 To, WdExportItem It
em, Boolean IncludeDocProps, Boolean KeepIRM, WdExportCreateBookmarks CreateBookmarks, Boolean DocStructureTags, Boolea
n BitmapMissingFonts, Boolean UseISO19005_1, Object& FixedFormatExtClassPtr)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
```

I have found nothing in the Event Viewer and have no idea what the problem is.  What could be causing this error?
Thanks

Comment: Word is a interactive gui application. Pretty sure you cant do this or should expect issues. There should be other examples of this. Even if you run it as com you are still doing it in an active user session. Why does it have to be in word? Could you use something else like... CutePDF I think could do this IIRC

Comment: Appreciate the input.

Comment: It's not quite what I am looking for though. I'd like to know what is so different about running the script in the Scheduled Job.